# How to access `matched_queries` in a `painless` script for creating buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with Elasticsearch 5.3.3 on AWS

I have multiple filters in a search query, each with an `_name`. These names are reflected in the results as `matched_queries`. I would like to group these results into different buckets where the selection criteria for each bucket is the presence of one or more of the filter names in `matched_queries`.

Here is an example request:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "terms": { "bed": [0, 1, 2] } },
        { "terms": { "contract": ["none", "good", "tight"] } }
      ],
      "should": [
        { 
          "terms": { 
            "bed": ["0", "1"],
            "_name": "exact_beds"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "bed": {
              "value": 2,
              "_name": "increased_beds"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "contract": ["good", "tight"],
            "_name": "money"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "contract": {
              "value": "none",
              "_name": "no_money"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It will output something like

```
{
  "took": 19,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 297256,
    "max_score": 5.8605247,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "listing",
        "_id": "49932563",
        "_score": 5.8605247,
        "_source": {
          "bed": 1,
          "contract": "good",
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "money",
          "exact_beds"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to add something like this to my request

```
"aggs": {
  "E1": {
    "filter": {
      "script": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "matched_queries.contains('exact_beds') && matched_queries.contains('money')"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But I get an error saying `"Variable [matched_queries] is not defined."`. Is there any way to access `matched_queries`?

Comment: No there is not, you cannot access `matched_queries` from your script aggregation. You can do what you need on the application side.

Comment: Thanks. Found a [discussion on the Elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/terms-aggregation-on-named-queries/62595) that explains why not.